# No output found after running the macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below mentioned macro and cannot find the output.
Could someone please let me know if there is something wrong in the macro and how to fix it?

Converted the code from imacros using iMacros Scripting Code Creator to VBS function and i have copied/pasted the same in VBA modules

```
Private Function macro() As String
macro = "CODE:"
macro = macro + "'Uses a Windows script to submit several datasets to a website, e. g. for filling an online database" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "' Specify input file (if !COL variables are used, IIM automatically assume a CSV format of the input file" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "'CSV = Comma Separated Values in each line of the filE" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "TAB T=1" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\Desktop\test\test.csv" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "'Start at line 2 to skip the header in the file" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "'Increase the current position in the file with each loop " + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "' Fill web form " + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "TAB T=1" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "URL GOTO=secured web page" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:asin CONTENT={{!COL1}}" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=TYPE:submit" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=CLASS:standardTable EXTRACT=TXT" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Users\Desktop\test FILE=test_image.csv" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "" + vbNewLine
End Function
```

Comment: What output are you looking for?  All the function does is return a `String`.  Do you want to know how to do `MsgBox macro()` or `Debug.Print macro()` in order to check the string?  Or are you wanting to know how to pass the string you create back to `iMacros` so that it can process the string as a script?

Comment: Your "code" is an iMacro.  You can't put it in Excel.  https://imacros.net/overview/

Comment: Output is that a table in webpage is copied and pasted in an excel sheet saved on the desktop. I want to know if it's possible using the above script - @ YowE3K

Answer (score 0):

1.) Actually it would be better to merge the strings with "&" instead of "+".

2.) To get the output you need a sub, which calls the function e.g.

```
Sub Use_Macro()
 Dim macroStr as String
   macroStr=macro
End Sub
```

Comment: mhm... that has to work. did a small sub myself? where are you looking for the output?

Comment: in Desktop and folder named test with the file test_image

Comment: ok, this wont work then. I actually dont know exactly what you want to do and am not able to help any further. Sorry. You should telll us exactly what youre trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to copy the whole table from a web page and paste it in the excel sheet..(txt format)

Answer (score 0):

In short: iMacro is not the same as an Excel Macro.  Also VB Script is not the same as Excel VBA.

"iMacros Scripting Code Creator" doesn't do anything of value. It does not convert a functioning iMacro to another language.  The only thing it does is take the text value of the iMacro and put it in a variable of the "language" it converts to.  The language it is converted to does not recognize iMacro language and will not execute. Even if it did convert something of value, VB Script cannot be used in Excel VBA.

Comment: Is there any way to convert imacro script to excel VBA??

Comment: No. You would have to design it from the ground up. Essentially, you would have to express the functionality of iMacro (which is written in C++) in VBA.  Is it impossible? No. But it is highly impractical. Excel VBA is designed to work with spreadsheets and charts of data, not web browsers and web forms.

Comment: So what would you suggest if I need to copy the table from a webpage to excel??

Comment: if its an html table, copy and paste usually works quite well. if you must to automate it, i would do some research on parsing html, and probably advise you to go with a language better suited to work with parsing html. like javascript and its slew of DOM frameworks

Comment: Why isn't it impractical to convert imacronto VBA??

Comment: instead of using Excel to get a table from a web page, use iMacro to extract the data, that's what it is designed to do.  http://wiki.imacros.net/Data_Extraction

Comment: Correct but I want the excel to be the only page that I work on and all the other stuff should happen in the background. One single step and button to pull data on to excel sheet

Comment: Then that would be a question for an iMacro expert.  Can't assist you any further. Good luck.